# How to bind datagridview to database?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview

I try to implement binding a `DataGridView` with database.

We can create a dataset, then choose one item an drag it to our control. It will create binding in the code behind. I use MVVM and I don't want to break this pattern.

**XAML**

```
     <Window.Resources>
        <DataSources:ServiceStationDBDataSet x:Key="serviceStationDBDataSet"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="serviceViewSource" Source="{Binding Service, Source={StaticResource serviceStationDBDataSet}}"/>
     </Window.Resources>
     <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Services"
        Style="{StaticResource MainDataGrid}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource serviceViewSource}}">             
     </DataGrid>
```

**C#(CodeBehind)**

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceStationDBDataSet serviceStationDBDataSet = ((ServiceStationDBDataSet)(this.FindResource("serviceStationDBDataSet")));
            // Load data into the table Service. You can modify this code as needed.
            ServiceTableAdapter DBDataSetServiceTableAdapter = new ServiceTableAdapter();
            DBDataSetServiceTableAdapter.Fill(serviceStationDBDataSet.Service);
            CollectionViewSource serviceViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("serviceViewSource")));
            serviceViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

        }
```

I want to create binding `DataGridView` with my MVVM class.

What can I do?

Comment: _"I want to create binding DataGridView with my **MVVM class**."_ - do you mean your VM class?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I made a mistake( It was very late, when I was writing this question(